# Access DOM from popup.js | Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a Chrome Extension that will take some of the contents of a page (The inner HTML of a `<span>` with `id="productTitile"`) I then would need to take that value and put it into a field in my popup.html.

I have tried this:

```
document.getElementById('input_87').value = chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.getElementById("productTitle").innerHTML'
});
```

But it just returns `undefined` into the field. I then ran `document.getElementById("productTitle").innerHTML` in the console in the parent page, and it gave me the expected value, but when I ran the whole code in console of the popup extension, it again returned undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is an asynchronous call, you should assign value inside its callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, as Haibara Ai says, `chrome.tabs.executeScript` is asynchronous - **it doesn't return anything** (and doesn't do anything immediately).

A good source on this in general is this question: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call?lq=1) *(spoiler: you can't)*

If you [look at the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) (which, by the way, should be your first unconditional reflex), you'll see that it has a callback and if you read the above question you'll understand it's your only option. However, there are 2  additional complications:

1. The callback gets an *array* of results. That happens because `executeScript` can, optionally (with `allFrames: true` or `frameId` specified), run in subframes. So you'll need to use the first element of the results array:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.executeScript({
     code: 'document.getElementById("productTitle").innerHTML'
   }, function(results) {
     document.getElementById('input_87').value = results[0];
   });
   ```
2. The call to `executeScript` can fail - for example, when the page is not scriptable regardless of permissions, such as the Chrome Web Store. It's wise to check that you actually got the result before using it:

   ```
   chrome.tabs.executeScript({
     code: 'document.getElementById("productTitle").innerHTML'
   }, function(results) {
     if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
       // Couldn't execute the script at all
     } else if (typeof results[0] === "undefined") {
       // Couldn't find what we wanted
     } else {
       // Everything is fine
       document.getElementById('input_87').value = results[0];
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: Hello @Xan, when will `executeScript` run in subframes if user has not specified the tabId, which defaults to the active tab?

Comment: If user has not specified `allFrames`, the return value would not be an array,  is that right?